# Navigation bar for pages in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to make my pages in wordpress, display categories. I've figured out how to display the category i want, query the `DB` like this

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php
query_posts('cat=7');
?>
```

Problem is that when i put the navbar for surfing pages, it doesn't work... it allways displays the 1st page...

This is the code i have for the entire page. I used the `Index.php` as the base.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Page4 */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div class="container_16 clearfix">
  <div class="grid_16 grid_content_sidebar">  

   <div class="grid_11 alpha">
     <div id="content">   

    <?php get_template_part( 'loop-meta' ); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php
 query_posts('cat=7');
 ?> 

      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content' ); ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

      <?php get_template_part( 'loop-error' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php infinity_loop_nav(); ?>

  </div> <!-- end #content -->
</div> <!-- end .grid_10 -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div> <!-- end .grid_16 -->

</div> <!-- end .container_16 -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I am using `Infinity template`. Can you help to figure what's the problem with the navbar, or maybe another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've figured out the problem. Just add this in the query line

```
.'&paged='.$paged
```

Looks like this now

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=7'.'&paged='.$paged);
?>
```